# PHP associative array not printing 1st and 5th keys

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

I have the PHP associative array as shown below, with mysql queries and filenames as keys and values:

```
$extract_queries = array( 
    "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '07:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '07:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate" => $current_user."-WinterNightTime1", 
    "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '07:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '07:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate" => $current_user."-SummerNightTime1",
    "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '16:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '16:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '16:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '16:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate" => $current_user."-WinterDayTime1",
    "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '18:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '18:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '18:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '18:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate" => $current_user."-WinterPeakTime",
    "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '22:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '22:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '22:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '22:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate" => $current_user."-WinterDayTime2",
    "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '22:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '22:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '22:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '22:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate" => $current_user."-SummerDayTime",
    "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '23:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '23:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '23:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate" => $current_user."-WinterNightTime2",
    "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '23:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '23:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '23:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate" => $current_user."-SummerNightTime2"
);
```

My problem is when I print_r($extract_queries);
The 1st and 5th keys and their values are missing from the array and even in a foreach loop they're being escaped.

How do I get those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary keys are duplicated in the 1st and 5th (the date/time is the same). Switch the SQL query to be the value and the `$current_user."-xxxTime1"` part to be the key

```
$extract_queries = array( $current_user."-WinterNightTime1" => "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '07:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '07:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate" => 
    ,$current_user."-SummerNightTime1" => "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '07:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '07:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate"
    ,$current_user."-WinterDayTime1" => "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '16:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '16:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '16:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '16:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate"
    ,$current_user."-WinterPeakTime" => "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '18:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '18:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '18:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '18:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate"
    ,$current_user."-WinterDayTime2" => "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '22:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '22:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '22:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '22:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate"
    ,$current_user."-SummerDayTime" => "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '22:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '22:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '22:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '22:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate"
    ,$current_user."-WinterNightTime2" => "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '23:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '23:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '23:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate"
    ,$current_user."-SummerNightTime2" => "SELECT  rec.time_stamp, rec.day_chan1, rec.day_chan2, rec.day_chan3 FROM ( SELECT ".$this->table_name.".*, DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate, TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '23:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '23:59:59') as rec JOIN ( SELECT DATE(time_stamp) as mydate, MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '23:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp) ) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime ORDER BY rec.mydate"
);
```

Comment: +1 also I would consider organizing my code better to avoid such trivial errors